# Les francophones comprennent-ils d'autres langues sans avoir à les apprendre?

Tags: comparaison-de-langues

J'habite en Amérique où les trois langues les plus importantes sont l'anglais, le portugais du Brésil et l'espagnol. Pour nous, hispanophones, si on écoute des anglais sans avoir étudié leur langue, c'est incompréhensible. En revanche, quand on écoute les lusophones, on peut comprendre entre 60% et 80% des conversations dans la majorité des cas, et parfois même 100%. La constat est vrai pour l’italien également, par exemple quand le Pape parle au Vatican, on comprend entre 50% et 70% de son discours.

Pour les personnes qui sont nées dans un pays ou une région francophone, y a-t-il des langues étrangères compréhensibles sans avoir pris de cours ou étudié quelque leçon ?

PS: J'ai essayé de créer le tag "intelligibilité-mutuelle" mais j'ai besoin d'avoir 150 point de réputation. (Effacez ce PS si vous créez le tag, s'il vous plaît)

Comment: Pour le personne qu'a envoyé l'édition de ma question en changeant **Amérique** pour **États-Unis**, je parle sur le continent américain, il serait très bizarre si je dis que j'habite aux États-Unis et que je suis hispanophone. Il peut être possible, mais il n'aurais pas de relation avec la question.

Comment: Très franchement, à part le Québécois, français à 99%, je ne vois pas

Comment: Thomas Francois, il faudrait faire plus attention lorsque vous éditez des questions.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant : Le Catalan s'en approche un peu.

Comment: @jecarfor Effectivement, je suis allé un peu vite :). Pour ta question, je suis d'accord avec Blue_Elephant. Je peux comprendre quelques mots d'espagnol ou d'italien, mais pas assez pour comprendre le discours.

Comment: Le portugais du Brésil a un impact singulier chez moi et j'ai souvent l'impression d'y entendre du français ; ce doit être la prononciation similaire de certains mots, comme par exemple Rickson Gracie dans Hulk, avec _emocao_... j'entends émotion avec un prononciation similaire à ce qu'on peut retrouver dans mon sociolecte (Québec) et donc c'est hypnotisant pour moi... ça me donne l'impression de comprendre...

Comment: Sans oublier les langues régionales !

Answer (score 7):

Bien que le vocabulaire soit relativement proche de l'italien, l'espagnol ou du catalan, le français est trop différent en rythme et accent tonique pour qu'il y ait une intercompréhension naturelle suffisante avec les autres langues romanes et pour qu'une conversation productive soit possible. De plus, au contraire des français, les italiens et les espagnols sont habitués à entendre une grande variété de dialectes de leur langues respectives ainsi que des langues régionales (appelés aussi dialectes en Italie), ce qui prédispose à la compréhension des autres langues romanes. Le portugais est lui très proche de l'espagnol et encore plus du galicien.

En restant en France mais en sortant de la francophonie, les personnes parlant couramment l'occitan, mais il n'y en a plus beaucoup, peuvent comprendre sans trop de difficulté les catalans, et réciproquement, les corsophones comprennent parfaitement l'italien, les alsacophones l'allemand, les catalanophones le catalan et les bascophones le basque...

Answer (score 5):

Comprendre juste en écoutant, non.

Lire et a peu près comprendre, oui, l'italien, l'espagnol et le catalan sont assez compréhensibles à cause de la similitude dans les formations des phrases, et les préfixes utilisés, je parle bien sûr de phrases relativement simples, pas d'un texte complexe bien évidemment.

Answer (score 1):

Alors ça dépend également des gens. Pour ma part si un Espagnol ou un Italien parle dans sa langue lentement, je comprends assez bien. Un portugais c’est plus compliqué car les sons sont carrément différents.

Pour les mots finissant par -ion l’espagnol ou l’anglais sont proches au niveau phonétique, mais ça ne nous empêche pas de comprendre le *-aõ* portugais ou le *-zione* italien.

Mon collègue italien m’a dit que lui comprenait 20-30% de ce qu’un français ou un espagnol disait mais qu’il ne comprenait ni le portugais ni le roumain.
Je pense que le portugais est difficile à comprendre à l’oral mais à l’écrit ça passe mais que le roumain pour moi ce n’est pas une langue latine mais plutôt slave.

Ensuite j’ai remarqué que les Italiens comprenaient mieux le français que les Espagnols mais que les Espagnols comprenaient mieux que les portugais.
Le français est une langue latine mais a des racines celtes et germanique également ce qui a rendu sa prononciation un peu différente des autres langues latines.

- Bouche — cavité buccale donc je comprends quand un espagnol dit *boca*

Ensuite l’anglais reste plus ou moins compréhensible pour certains Français car plus de 30% du vocabulaire anglais vient du français notamment du vieux français ou d’un dialecte normand et à 25% du latin.
C’est pour ça que les Anglais ne comprennent ni l’allemand ni le français.

Comment: *Boca* sans autre contexte n'est compréhensible pour un Français que s'il a déjà des bases de vocabulaire espagnol et qu'il connait les "trucs" qui permettent de deviner comment bon nombre de mots latins ont pu évoluer dans cette langue. En tout état de cause, c'est insuffisant pour avoir une vraie conversation avec un Espagnol. D'autre part, considérer que le roumain n'est pas une langue latine (c'est à dire romane) est assez audacieux...